# How can I create animated gif in Java?

Tags: java, animated-gif

I would like to create a gif image from the set of BufferedImages. How can I do this? Is there such library in pure Java (ImageMagick is not an option)? I've found Gif4J library but it's not royality-free.

Comment: Try this [gif encoder](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm). **Related Question:** - [Creating Animated-gif with imageio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777947/creating-animated-gif-with-imageio)

Comment: There is also this http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/ which seems to work well.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) link and the wiki examples there will do what you want. You can control the frame rate as well. It's pure Java. You may not even need to use imageio! – dragon66 Sep 19 '14 at 19:47

Comment: And [this](https://github.com/dragon66/animated-gif-writer) easy to use standalone AnimatedGIFWriter.

Answer (score 3):

I just answer a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326165/2756827), but I think that my solution can help.

'ImageIcon' class allows you to load gif animations. I load the image with 'getResource()'. For doing this I normally us URL class to pass the file path. The path does not need to be necessary in a remote machine as the name URL may suggest.

```
URL url = This.class.getResource(path);
Icon myImgIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel imageLbl = new JLabel(myImgIcon);
component.add(imageLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

path will be the path of the gif inside of the class folder.

References:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource

Answer (score 0):

There is an image processing library, akin to [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which uses the very same AnimatedGifEncoder class mentioned by Lifelogger-
[Glide Docs](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/index.html), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
 AnimatedGifEncoder e = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
 e.start(outputFileName);
 e.setDelay(1000);   // 1 frame per sec
 e.addFrame(image1);
 e.addFrame(image2);
 e.finish();
```