# How do I create an animated gif from an array of bufferedimages?

Tags: java, gif, bufferedimage

I have an array of buffered images and I want to create a gif with them. I also want to be able to specify the delay between the the images. Is there anything in the java api which would be able to provide this? I haven't been able to find anything

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you changed "gif" to "animated gif" in both your question's opening sentence and in its title.

Comment: I have seen answers to similar questions but I don't believe any of them sufficiently answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try the AnimatedGifEncoder code here :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm

The question has been asked a lot :

[How can I create animated gif in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349750/how-can-i-create-animated-gif-in-java)

[Creating animated GIF with ImageIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777947/creating-animated-gif-with-imageio)

EDIT:
And even here : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1264385

Comment: I have seen these questions previously, I did not find them helpful

Comment: I don't think Java SE provide, in standard, the feature you request : "Create an animated gif from buffered images". You will have to hand code a minimum.

Comment: @Gilligan94, I agree with you;  many people are providing links to other StackOverflow questions or to various other pages, but none of those provide a working ImageIO-based solution.  It's unfortunate that this question was closed, as I did some research and found that it can indeed be done with pure ImageIO:  Use `ImageWriter.writeToSequence` for each frame, set the delay in each frame's IIOMetadata, and set the repeat count in the first frame's IIOMetadata.

Comment: @VGR thanks a lot, I find stack exchange has this problem, in fact most reputation/points based support sites do. People are quite to attack you for asking a question that has been asked before no matter how poorly the previous answers were or how different your question is. it's very dissapointing

Comment: Didn't know of `ImageWriter.writeToSequence` before @VGR mentioned it. Not easy to find actually, sorry ...