# Is there a way to create one Gif image from multiple images in Java?

Tags: java, jpeg, gif, bufferedimage

I am trying to set up a simple Java program that creates one single animated gif from multiple other images (jpg). Can anyone give me a hook on how to achieve this in Java? I already searched Google but couldn't find anything really helpful.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you mean an animated gif? or do you want a large gif made of a few smaller gif? Or do you want to paste one gif on another using gif's transparency?

Comment: I want an animated gif.

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki) has much more information than just create animated GIF.

Comment: And [this](https://github.com/dragon66/animated-gif-writer) standalone animated GIF writer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here you have an example of a class that creates an animated gif from different images:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191226041038/elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java)

*Edit: links seems to be dead. Anyway, just to be clear, this code was done by Elliot Kroo.*

**Edit 2: Thanks to [`@Marco13`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182664/marco13) for finding the WayBack Machine link. Updated the reference!**

The class provides these methods:

```
class GifSequenceWriter {
    public GifSequenceWriter(
        ImageOutputStream outputStream,
        int imageType,
        int timeBetweenFramesMS,
        boolean loopContinuously);

    public void writeToSequence(RenderedImage img);

    public void close();
}
```

And also a little example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  if (args.length > 1) {
    // grab the output image type from the first image in the sequence
    BufferedImage firstImage = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));

    // create a new BufferedOutputStream with the last argument
    ImageOutputStream output = 
      new FileImageOutputStream(new File(args[args.length - 1]));

    // create a gif sequence with the type of the first image, 1 second
    // between frames, which loops continuously
    GifSequenceWriter writer = 
      new GifSequenceWriter(output, firstImage.getType(), 1, false);

    // write out the first image to our sequence...
    writer.writeToSequence(firstImage);
    for(int i=1; i<args.length-1; i++) {
      BufferedImage nextImage = ImageIO.read(new File(args[i]));
      writer.writeToSequence(nextImage);
    }

    writer.close();
    output.close();
  } else {
    System.out.println(
      "Usage: java GifSequenceWriter [list of gif files] [output file]");
  }
}
```

Props to [Elliot Kroo](http://elliot.kroo.net/) for this code.

Comment: It is good to include main part of linked content in answer, in case link goes offline.

Comment: You only included interface of class `GifSequenceWriter` (there is not body in constructor and methods, so we cant really use it). What is most important is [how was it implemented](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java).

Comment: How do I use that code?

Comment: @user2399314 I updated this answer a little. Take a look at the link. You will find code of `GifSequenceWriter` class there. Now you can use it like in example shown in this answer.

Comment: @Asier Aranbarri there is only one problem: the gif animation does not behave like normal gif since it does not loop :(

Comment: @Asier Aranbarri I already fixed it. I just needed to change the loop setting from 'false' to 'true'.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Does this compute a gif with 8-bit or 24-bit colors?

Comment: Where it generates the .gif file?

Comment: The last argument is the location of the out.file:     // create a new BufferedOutputStream with the last argument
    ImageOutputStream output = 
      new FileImageOutputStream(new File(args[args.length - 1]));

Comment: It works, but the image quality is low.  I'm having trouble setting it by tweaking ImageWriteParam settings.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for that advice, years after. Links are sadly gone.

Comment: The wayback machine still got it: https://web.archive.org/web/20191226041038/elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java

Comment: Not able to understand why the question has been closed. The problem statement is clear and the answer is spot on.

Comment: Just in case Wayback Machine link breaks, someone has created a Github Gist with the same file -> https://gist.github.com/jesuino/528703e7b1974d857b36