# How to write back BufferedImage(s) into animated .gif and save it

Tags: java, gif, javax.imageio, steganography

I'm trying to make steganography for .gif images. But I stuck when I want write/save changed image as animated gif.
This sample of code pulls out separated images from gif but I can't figure out how to write them back to animated .gif image and save it.

```
File file = new File("gif1.gif");
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("GIF").next();
ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
reader.setInput(in);


ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("GIF").next();
ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream("new.gif");
writer.setOutput(out);

for (int i = 0, count = reader.getNumImages(true); i < count; i++)
{
    BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
}
```

I will be gratefull for any help.

Comment: You have no idea what you are getting your self into! Do your self a favor and use `ImageIcon` instead of `ImageIO`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188940/gif-image-doesnt-moves-on-adding-it-to-the-jtabbed-pane/22190844#22190844

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777947/creating-animated-gif-with-imageio - using ImageIcon might be easier though...

Comment: @DimaMaligin In what way would using `ImageIcon` help with *writing* `BufferedImage`s to an animated GIF?