# How To Convert a Image to a BufferedImage without loosing a GIFs animation

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So I was wondering how I could convert an Image (from java.awt.Image) to a BufferedImage without loosing the GIFS animation. Im working on a method which gets a `byte[]` (an Image as byte array) then I need to translate it to a `Image` (with a `ByteArrayInputStream`), resize it, and then return the newly resized image back as `byte[]`. The problem is `BufferedImage.getScaledInstace(...)` returns an `java.awt.Image`, but I need a `BufferedImage` to convert it back to a `byte[]`.

My code so far:

```
private byte[] resizeImage(byte[] bytes, String format, int size) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    double ratio = (double) image.getHeight() / (double) image.getWidth();
    Image newImage = image.getScaledInstance(size, (int) (size * ratio), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    
    // TODO: Convert into byte array
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible.  An animated GIF is a *sequence* of images.  But a `BufferedImage` represents a single image.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054058 ... whose comments also say that it isn't possible to represent an animated GIF as a **single** `BufferedImage`.

Comment: The dup link gives a practical solution.